# React Native Flatlist scrollToEnd after new item added

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I need to scroll to the end of FlatList after adding of new list item (like a chat).
So I change state with new message and then use:

```
this.setState({messages});
this.messagesList.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
```

It wotks only if I add some 'magic' setTimeout (200ms).
It there any way to detect that new message is added and I can call scrollToEnd?

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous so doing something after it like that will not work.

To do something after state it's set - pass callback to `setState` as second argument.

```
this.setState(
    {messages}, 
    () => this.messagesList.scrollToEnd({animated: true})
);
```

But from my experience you will need still have short `setTimeout`. As after setting state there can be some lag created by rendering and scroll will be fired too early.

Comment: Thx for the note about setState. But yes, it's still require some timeout (and not 0 but some number) and I worry this timeout may not work for slow devices. But in a while ScrollView works fine, so looks like it's related with 'smart rendering' behaviour of FlatList component.

Comment: if my answer 'solved' Your issue then please don't forget about accepting it.